# Remove hyperlink from figure captions

Tags: hyperref, captions

I have been asked by the a journal editor to remove the blue highlighting (i.e., hyperlinks) in all figure captions. The following MWE generates the below output (provided that the [ctanlion.eps](http://www.ctan.org/lion/files/ctanlion.eps) file is saved in the working folder).:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true,
  citecolor = blue,
  linkcolor = blue,
  urlcolor = blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{ctanlion.eps} 
\caption{CTAN lion draw­ing by Duane Bibby; thanks to www.ctan.org}
\label{fig:Figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{ctanlion.eps} 
\caption{Same as Fig~\ref{fig:Figure1}}
\label{fig:Figure2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The red annotations are manually added on top of the latex output to better explain my request.

Comment: `\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}` in your preamble if you want to remove colored links in your whole document.

Comment: I don't want to remove them globally. Only in the figure captions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing \ref{} with \ref*{} in the captions (or elsewhere) does the job.